# Haskell: check the length of IO [Double]

Tags: haskell, monads, functor

Given a list of type `IO [Double]`, I want to be able to check that the list is of the desired length.

I'm guessing I need to make use of functors here, but I don't understand how to go about defining it. Do I write a functor instance of the length function? Or do I write a functor instance of a data type that uses the length function in `fmap`?

Monads, functors, etc. are all pretty new to me.

Comment: You write a functor instance for the "action" you work in: `IO`. Except of course you don't actually need to do that yourself, the instance is already defined in the prelude; all that's left for you to do is _invoke_ that instance, by using `fmap` once.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A value of type `IO [Double]` does not have a length, because it is not a list of Doubles, but rather an IO action which, when performed, will produce a list of Doubles. So, it is impossible to write a function of type `IO [a] -> Int`.

However, you can easily write a function of type `IO [a] -> IO Int`, which is as simple as `fmap length`.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, what you want to do is obtain the list, and then compute it's length.  Generally, you will want to do this with do notation (although it isn't strictly necessary).

Haskell encapsulates all IO in the IO monad, so you can only obtain the list from the `IO [Double]` in another object of type `IO a`.  The code will look something like this-

```
main::IO ()
main = do
  theList <- getList --or whatever your object of type IO [Double] is
  let theLength = length theList
  ....  -- Do stuff with theLength here
```

Comment: It's more natural to do it like this if you need the list for something other than its length, as well. But the `fmap` approach can be better in other circumstances.

Comment: @dfeuer- the `fmap` approach is generally what I would do, but this is what I would show a beginner first.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the answers posted so far are correct and good ways of solving this problem, but I'd like to point a third syntax to accomplish the same effect. This is effectively [jamshidh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26855661/1530508) minus the syntactic sugar of `do`-notation:

```
ioLength :: IO [Double] -> IO Int
ioLength a = a >>= (\x -> return $ length x)
```

Or, more concisely:

```
ioLength a = a >>= (return . length)
```

Which, if condensed even further, yields [amalloy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26855583/1530508):

```
ioLength = fmap (length)
```